# What am I afraid of? and why?

Tags: riddle, wordplay, rhyme

> In a land of no name you start your journey with hands stuck at 3,
>   there is a tree with two stumps, a half moon you will see.
>   A fork in the way two roads there must be.
>   This tree as your guide you travel to mountains only to see this tree before 3.
>   Onwards you go to a valley that's mirrored after a quick break for some tea.
>   Amazed by your eyes with this valley a new twist on 3 is just what you see.
>   Frustrated at least, this tree again, all of it over, here it ends.

What am I afraid of? and why?

**Hint:**

> A fork in the way two roads there must be = **Y**
>  This tree as your guide = **A**
>  This tree before 3 = **AL**

Comment: I've added some line breaks that clarify (some of) the rhymes. @rsp, feel free to revert if you don't like that.

Comment: Are you sure this is [logical-deduction]? I see no actual deduction that can be made - if anything, this is more of a riddle.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Most of the clues were from other people, but I think the final answer is

> Lady Amalthea

Each letter of this comes from:

> L - Hands on a clock at 3 o'clock
>  A - Tree (triangle) with 2 stumps
>  D - Half moon/circle
>  Y - A forking road
>  A - Repeated hint
>  M - Pointed mountaintops
>  A - Repeated hint
>  L - Repeated hint
>  T - Tea
>  H - An odd valley, mirrored top to bottom
>  E - A new twist on 3, in that it's a mirrored 3 (as opposed to the clock)
>  A - Repeated hint

From this answer it seems that you are

> King Haggard, from "The Last Unicorn." You are afraid of Lady Amalthea because you think she will free all of the unicorns you have in captivity.

Answer (score 4):

I think I might be afraid of

> making rounds in the land of no name for eternity.

Because I am

> the hands of a clock (or watch) with roman digits

In a land of no name you start your journey with hands stuck at 3,

> I have 3 hands and will never have more: hours, minutes and seconds (or alternatively 2 hands of the clock and one hand of the owner)

there is a tree with two stumps,

> we could be talking about the hour 12 (XII) here. The II representing the trunk of a tree, but I'm not convinced about the X as the two stumps...

a half moon you will see.

> some watches have [moon phases](https://www.watchcollectinglifestyle.com/home/insider-breguet-classique-ref-7787-hands-on-with-a-simple-elegant-and-beautiful-timepiece)

A fork in the way two roads there must be.

> Assuming the riddle starts at time 9, the hour 10 (X) represents a crossroad on my way up

This tree as your guide you travel to mountains only to see this tree before 3.

> the hands are climbing all the way up to 12, only to see another tree in 2 (II)

Onwards you go to a valley that's mirrored after a quick break for some tea.

> You start your downward journey towards symmetrical hours: IV V VI. 5 o'clock is tea time in England, and also the center of that symmetry

Amazed by your eyes with this valley a new twist on 3 is just what you see.

> down at hour 6, you start seing VIII, which is similar to III

Frustrated at least, this tree again, all of it over, here it ends.

> from there you see again the tree at XII and realize you will climb the same mountain and go down the same valley for ever.

What a frightening thought.

Answer (score 2):

No need to vote on this community-wiki partial possible solution,
here only in case it is on the right path
and someone else can figure out more of it.

Suppose that each stage of the poem...

> ...describes a letter in a phrase.

In a land of no name you start your journey with hands stuck at 3,

> **B** looks somewhat like a stick-figure person grasping a **3**.

there is a tree with two stumps,

> **A** looks like a ∧-shaped tree standing on two stumpy legs.

a half moon you will see.

> **D** looks very much like a half moon.

So far, so...

> **B A D**,...

...which seems like the start of something to fear.
From here, though, things look more confusing than scary.

A fork in the way two roads there must be.

> **Y** (or **T**) ?

This tree as your guide you travel

> **A** ?

to mountains

> **M** ?

only to see

> **C** ?

this tree

> **A** ?

before 3.

> **B** ?

Onwards you go to a valley that's mirrored

> **X** ?  (V mirrored, as if above a lake)

after a quick break for some tea.

> **T** ?

Amazed by your eyes

> **I** ?

with this valley

> **V** ?

a new twist on 3 is just what you see.

> **S** ?

Frustrated at least, this tree again,

> **A** ?

all of it over, here it ends.

> Whew.  The only harm actually suffered was by the possible result,
>  
>  **B A D   Y A M C A B X T I V S A**,...

...which just can’t be entirely correct.

Comment: Perhaps a W for a mirrored V...

Answer (score 2):

Partial answer here, incorporating some helpful hints from OP:

Looking at each clue as a hint to a letter of the alphabet...

In a land of no name you start your journey with hands stuck at 3

> The hands of a clock at 3 o'clock looks like **L**

there is a tree with two stumps, a half moon you will see.

> Since clue below is **Y**, guessing tree with two stumps should be something else. **U**? half moon = **D**

A fork in the way two roads there must be.

> OP says this is **Y**

This tree as your guide you travel to mountains only to see this tree before 3.

> Tree as your guide is **A** according to OP. 3 here refers again to **L**.

Onwards you go to a valley that's mirrored after a quick break for some tea.

> Imagine two Vs upside down, with a T in the middle - looks like **M** to me!

Amazed by your eyes with this valley a new twist on 3 is just what you see.

> A twist on 3 = 3 reversed = **E**

Frustrated at least, this tree again, all of it over, here it ends.

> Not sure which tree is repeated, going to guess **A**.

Putting it all together

> We have LUDYALMEA, which STILL makes absolutely no sense to me... It seems to make more sense if clue #2 referred to **A**, maybe the stumps point downwards? Then we have LADY something, which at least seems to be a better start.

Comment: I have added hint. may be help you.